# How to refactor app.getwith different routes but same actions in node.js

Tags: node.js

I would like to simplify a piece of my code but not sure how to do it.
I have

```
// Monitoring route
app.get('/ping', (req, res)=>{
  res.send('Hello World!');
})

// Route that receives a GET
app.get('/getCar', (req, res)=>{  routes.get(req, res);})
app.get('/getCarList', (req, res)=>{  routes.get(req, res);})
app.get('/getDriver', (req, res)=>{  routes.get(req, res);})
app.get('/getDriverList', (req, res)=>{  routes.get(req, res);})
app.get('/getCarDriver', //do something else than the rest)
```

So what I would like is to get the four app.get doing the same thing together.
I have starting by thinking of doing a function for the result like this :

```
var getSendRes = (req, res)=>{  routes.get(req, res);}
```

But I think it would be better if I merged all app.get doing the same stuff together. Any idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to bind the `routes.get` function, so you can reference it each time instead of typing it out:

```
const getBound = routes.get.bind(routes);
app.get('/getCar', getBound);
app.get('/getCarList', getBound);
// etc
```

If you have a whole lot, you could iterate over an array of route strings instead:

```
for (const str of ['getCar', 'getCarList', 'getDriver', 'getDriverList']) {
  app.get('/' + str, (req, res) => { routes.get(req, res); }
}
```